# Scala class constructor lot of fields

Tags: scala, class, reflection, hbase

I have a class with a primary constructor that takes more than 50 fields:

```
class HBaseEve   (val rowKey: String,
                 ...
                  val customer: String,
                 ...
                  val managedEntityKey: String,
                 ...
                  val withdrawalReasonForWithdrawal: String)
```

In my companion object, I declared a method called parse to create a HBaseEve object from a record in HBase table:

```
    object HBaseEve {
final val COLUMN_FAMILY = "cr"
  override def parse(result: Result): HBaseEve  = {
    if (result.getRow != null)
      new HBaseEve   (
        Bytes.toString(result.getRow),
      ...
        Bytes.toString(result.getValue(HBaseEve.COLUMN_FAMILY.getBytes(), "customer".getBytes())),
        ...
Bytes.toString(result.getValue(HBaseEve.COLUMN_FAMILY.getBytes(), "managedEntityKey".getBytes())),
        ...
        Bytes.toString(result.getValue(HBaseEve.COLUMN_FAMILY.getBytes(), "withdrawalReasonForWithdrawal".getBytes()))
      )
    else null
  }
```

However, this method parse is not very elegant because I have more than 50 fields in my class to fill in manually. 
I do not have any idea how to replace this method parse by other method more efficient and profissional.

Any idea on this? I searched about scala.Reflection but i do not have any ideia how to use this. Anyway, i am open to any ideias please.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not really sure there's a better way to call a 50 param constructor then by just calling the 50 param constructor. If you don't like how big the constructor is, there are lots of approaches to reducing it. However the easiest will be just having a 50 param constructor. TL;DR: It's fine as is.

Comment: any ideia in order to reduce it?

Comment: wrap up related fields into case classes. For example if you have user data, create a `case class User(...)` with all the user fields. Remove all the user fields from HBaseEve and add a `val user: User` field -- this won't really make constructing it any cleaner. You still have to parse all the data no matter what.

Comment: What about Reflection? do you know it?

Comment: even with reflection, you will have to parse or otherwise produce a value for each field. There's no magic here to create your data. Reflection is also brittle and prone to errors and IMO should be avoided where possible (which is most of the time). Reflection also makes things like Proguard and GraalVM harder to use and generally your code becomes less portable.

Comment: If you are parsing from JSON you can use something like crice to auto generate a parser but I'm not sure if it works with a class of 50 fields.

Comment: Can you show me an example with circe? I was thinking about a method apply in class HBaseEve like this `def apply(a: Array[HBaseEveField]) = {do some magic to assign each value to the respective field}`

Comment: a method with that signature won't work without fairly complicated/verbose reflection. With circe, you can auto generate a json parser with `val d = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder[HBaseEve]` Once you have that decoder, you can call `io.circe.parser.decode[HBaseEve](jsonString)(d)`. You will get an `Either[Error, HBaseEve]` from decode. https://circe.github.io/circe/

Comment: wait, my object that i fetch from HBase is result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result. So, according to your suggestion, i have to convert it somehow to JSON format and then parse it. right?

Comment: yep, more likely, you'll just want to do what you're doing. There's no shortcut to parsing data. JSON is a special case. It's so widespread, there are lots of tools to deal with parsing. HBase doesn't have the same luxury so you'll just have to roll your own parsing.

Comment: Did you consider using Avro?